# how to convert date type field data to unixtimestamp in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

in es, `created_at` as a date type

```
created_at: {
 type: "date",
 format: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
},
```

i want use created_at as a UnixTimeStamp epoch seconds in `script_score` calculation. how to implement this?

```
 (doc['created_at'].value.to_unixtimestamp? - 1412092800)/86400.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, either like this

```
((doc['created_at'].value / 1000) - 1412092800)/86400.0
```

or like this:

```
((doc['created_at'].date.millis / 1000) - 1412092800)/86400.0
```

Comment: my raw data is `"created_at": "2015-11-02T18:43:54.000+08:00"`, when i use `doc['created_at'].value/1000`, the output is `3339851260`, why not `1446461034`

Comment: What about the second option?

Comment: `doc['created_at'].date.millis / 1000` as well get `3339851260` @Val

Comment: sorry, @Val,  is my mistake, in elasticsearch function_score i'v forget add `"boost_mode": "replace"`, thanks